# How can I reduce the time that Eclipse PDT needs to startup?

Tags: eclipse-pdt

I'm a very patient guy but seems very annoying the long time that Eclipse takes to let me start working.

Why is that? I have a clean PDT distribution download form the Zend site. No extra plugins added.

Is this only happening to me? Does anyone else notice this delay?

Best,
Demian

Comment: as a side note, you should accept more answers.

Comment: Sorry Pablo, you are right, I'm new in SO.

Comment: Try also this eclipse.ini http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run eclipse from the command line with these arguments to assign more memory to it:

`eclipse -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx1g`

Note: I assume you have a RAM of 2 or more gigs