# How to stop building workspace once started

Tags: php, eclipse

I've seen posts that explain how to disable automatic building of workspace. I added a really large project and it's already started the automatic build, but it's taking forever because the project is really huge. While it's building, I can't do anything with eclipse. If I Ctrl + Alt + Delete and end eclipse, it starts the build workspace again when it re-launches eclipse (and again I can't do anything with eclipse). Is there a short cut to stop a build once it's started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Progress view you can try to stop the build. It does not work every time, but if you are fast enough, you could stop it this way. And then you could race to disable automatic build hoping it won't start again until that point.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definitive answer, but might help you until you find out how to do what you want.

[Assign more memory to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278785/how-can-i-reduce-the-time-that-eclipse-pdt-needs-to-startup)

Hope it helps